# Link main function from static library into exe

Tags: c++, c, linkage

I'm trying to link a `main` function from a static library into an executable and i'm getting the following error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main

I'm using VC++12.0.

Is it not possible to link `main` from a static library?

Thanks

Comment: It should be possible to link a `main()` from a static library. What is your `main()`'s exact signature?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Its signature is `int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])`

Comment: What library are you using? One you made yourself? One you have downloaded? Why do you have the `main` function in a library?

Comment: Given the _tmain, you may be missing a consistent UNICODE definition between the library and the exe.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I made it myself. I had a standalone executable and now I'm trying to move its logic into a static library so that I can link it with a unit-test project. I understand that this is not a BKM and I'm planning to move the `main` from the library into the executable in the future.

Comment: @Niall Both projects (executable and static library) use UNICODE character set.

Comment: I can reproduce this with `UNICODE` defined (thus `_tmain` maps to `wmain`) with `_tmain` in the lib. When not using `UNICODE` (thus `_tmain` maps to `main`), it all links fine. This may or may not be a bug, you can always file it at https://connect.microsoft.com/ and see what they say. VS seems to have different linking rules/process depending on the target being `main` or `wmain`; either way the "best" thing to do is move `main` into the executable anyway.

Comment: If you do report it, please post a link to the issue here, would be nice to have for future reference, what the outcome was.